# Dynamic string array in C

Tags: c, malloc, c-strings, realloc, function-definition

I was trying to code something to practice the C langage.
What I wanted to do (again only to practice, not for any use) was to create some kind of inventory system on which you could add an item in or take an item out.

I decided to implement it with a dynamic string array. Since I'm quite new to C, it was a hard time actualy understanding what was going on with the pointers and stuff, but I eventually got it.

I managed to code something. But I have an issue that I cannot seem to debug, I don't understand where it comes from, here's my code (probably really cursed)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int addItemToInventory(char ***Inv_content,int *Inv_length,char* Item)
{
    int item_name_size=strlen(Item);
    if (*Inv_length==0) //If The size of the inventory is 0, I have to create the array.
    {
        *Inv_content = malloc((1) * sizeof(char*));
        if (*Inv_content) // malloc succeed
        {
            *Inv_content[0] = malloc((item_name_size+1) * sizeof(char));
            if (*Inv_content[0]) // malloc succeed
            {
                strcpy(*Inv_content[0], Item);
                *Inv_length+=1;
            }

            else // malloc failed
            {
                printf("Impossible to allocate memory for item '%s' in InvContent[0] \n", Item);
                return(2);
            }
        }

        else // malloc failed
        {
            printf("Impossible to allocate memory for Inv. (Create New Inv)\n");
            return(1);
        }
        
    }

    else //the size of the inventory is greater than zero, I have to expand the current array and add the item to the new slot
    {
        char **tmp_pnt;
        tmp_pnt= realloc(*Inv_content, (*Inv_length+1) * sizeof(char*));

        if (tmp_pnt)
        {
            *Inv_content=tmp_pnt;
            *Inv_content[*Inv_length] = malloc((item_name_size+1) * sizeof(char));

            if (*Inv_content[*Inv_length])
            {
                strcpy(*Inv_content[*Inv_length], Item);
                *Inv_length+=1;
            }

            else // malloc failed
            {
                printf("unable to allocate memory for item '%s' in InvContent[%d]\n", Item, *Inv_length);
                return(2);
            } 
        }
        else // realloc failed
        {
            printf("Impossible to allocate memory for Inv. (Add Item (realloc))\n");
            return(1);
        }
        
    }

    return(0);
}
```

So, I hope the code was clear enough, as you can see, this function takes 3 parameters :

- a pointer to the inventory itself (In order to make changes directly to it)
- a pointer to the size of the inventory, for the same reason
- and the item name that we want to add

Now comes the issue, here's the main function I made to test my function:

```
int main()
{
    //int run = 1;
    char **Inv_content = NULL;
    int Inv_length=0;
    //int Item_index=-1;
    char Item1[12]="Great Sword";
    char Item2[8]="Big Bow";

    addItemToInventory(&Inv_content, &Inv_length, Item1);
    addItemToInventory(&Inv_content, &Inv_length, Item2);

    printf("\n");
    for (int i=0; i<=Inv_length-1;i++)
    {
        printf ("Item %d : %s \n", i, Inv_content[i]);
    }

}
```

and here's the result:

- Item 1: Great sword
- Item 2: (NULL)

When calling the function once, no problems, I figured that the first part of my function (Case when size = 0) works fine.
When calling a second time, it outputs "(null)" as a result, like if there was nothing there in the array.
and when calling a third time (or more), it's even worse, it crashes with "segmentation error".

Here's what I figured out, the second part works as intended, when `printf("%s", *Inv_content[1])` inside the function even at the end of it, it outputs "Big bow", like intended, but as soon as it leaves the function, when printing inv_content[1] it outputs (null) like if it was wiped when the function exit.

Lastly, I don't understand why I've got a segmentation error when calling 3+ times, since it doesn't with 2 (which should be the same case)

Anyway, I hope you guys can help me understand a bit more what's happening so I could not make these mistakes in the future :)
Thank you

Comment: Sidenote: Use `size_t` for array length, for example to store the return value of `strlen()`. There is a reason C has so many types for integers. Also: `sizeof(char)` is grantee to be 1, no need to multiply by it.

Comment: Recommendation: define `typedef struct { char ** data; size_t size; size_t capacity; } StringArray;` to avoid being a [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function should be declared at least like

```
int addItemToInventory( char ***Inv_content, size_t *Inv_length, const char *Item );
```

Secondly there is no sense to split the body of the function into two parts depending on the condition

```
if (*Inv_length==0)
```

And the function contains bugs in statements like for example that

```
*Inv_content[*Inv_length] = malloc((item_name_size+1) * sizeof(char));
```

You need to write

```
( *Inv_content )[*Inv_length] = malloc((item_name_size+1) * sizeof(char));
```

The function can look the following way

```
int addItemToInventory( char ***Inv_content, size_t *Inv_length, const char *Item )
{
    char **tmp_pnt =  realloc( *Inv_content, ( *Inv_length +1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );

    int result = tmp_pnt != NULL ? 0 : 1;

    if ( result == 0 )
    {
        *Inv_content = tmp_pnt;

        ( *Inv_content )[*Inv_length] = malloc( strlen( item ) + 1 ); 

        if ( ( *Inv_content )[*Inv_length] == NULL ) result = 2;

        if ( result == 0 )
        {
            strcpy( ( *Inv_content )[*Inv_length], Item );
            ++*Inv_length;
        }
    }
        
    return result;
}
```

Pay attention to that the function should not issue any message.

It is the caller of the function that will decide whether to output a message based on the return value of the function or not.

Also instead of using magic numbers like 0, 1, and 2 within the function you could introduce an enumeration as for example

```
enum { Success = 0, ReallocFailure = 1, MallocFailure = 2 };
```

and within the function write for example

```
    int result = tmp_pnt != NULL ? Success : ReallocFailure;

    if ( result == Success )
    //... and so on
```

There is some serious problem with the function. If a character array for the string `item` was not allocated the array of pointers nevertheless was already reallocated. So the function behavior will be logically inconsistent.

It is better to rewrite the function the following way

```
enum { Success = 0, ReallocFailure = 1, MallocFailure = 2 };

int addItemToInventory( char ***Inv_content, size_t *Inv_length, const char *Item )
{
    char *s = malloc( strlen( item ) + 1 );

    int result = s != NULL ? Success : MallocFailure;

    if ( result == Success )
    {
        char **tmp_pnt =  realloc( *Inv_content, ( *Inv_length +1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );

       if ( tmp_pnt == NULL ) result = ReallocFailure;

       if ( result == Success )
       {
            strcpy( s, Item );

            tmp_pnt[*Inv_length] = s;

            *Inv_content = tmp_pnt;

            ++*Inv_length;
        }
        else
        {
            free( s );
        }
    }
        
    return result;
}
```

That function looks more clear and has no logical inconsistence.

Comment: Thank you for the time you put into that answer, I've understood what was wrong and took the time to learn what was going on. Thanks too for the tips on magic numbers and no messages in the function itself, I'll make sure to remember this

Answer (score 1):

`*Inv_content[*Inv_length]` is looking next to your array to the next array in memory (which may or may not be allocated). You want to use `(*Inv_content)[*Inv_length]` instead which looks for the selected item *inside the array* instead.

Also, here's a somewhat less cursed version of your code, you're rewriting at least `strdup` in your code and using wrong size types:

```
typedef struct { const char* Name; } Item;

int addItemToInventory(Item** Inv_content, size_t* Inv_length, const char* Item)
{
    if (*Inv_length == 0)
    {
        *Inv_content = malloc(sizeof(struct Item*));
        if (*Inv_content)
            (*Inv_content)->Name = _strdup(Item);
        *Inv_length = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        char** tmp_pnt;
        tmp_pnt = realloc(*Inv_content, (*Inv_length + 1) * sizeof(struct Item*));

        if (tmp_pnt)
        {
            *Inv_content = tmp_pnt;
            (*Inv_content)[(*Inv_length)++].Name = _strdup(Item);
        }
        else // realloc failed
        {
            printf("Impossible to allocate memory for Inv. (Add Item (realloc))\n");
            return(1);
        }
    }

    return(0);
}

int main()
{
    Item* Inv_content = NULL;
    size_t Inv_length = 0;

    const char Item1[] = "Great Sword";
    const char Item2[] = "Big Bow";

    addItemToInventory(&Inv_content, &Inv_length, Item1);
    addItemToInventory(&Inv_content, &Inv_length, Item2);

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= Inv_length - 1; i++)
        printf("Item %d : %s \n", i, Inv_content[i].Name);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it does work and is actualy closer to my original code. Thanks for taking the time to uncurse my code!

Answer (score 1):

I want to start by pointing out that you are doing [three star programming](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). What you call an Inventory, actually wants to be an `Inventory` container of `InventoryItem` objects. You don't have to respect this, but then you should write more documentation to make up for the complexity, as a single pointer is complex enough due to it being unclear whether it points to the heap, the stack, or anything else just by looking at it. This complexity also makes it more difficult to make changes to your design, partially due to a sense of "sunk time cost" of wrangling with the pointers, and partially due to heavy coupling to the implementation details of what an `InventoryItem` is.

I would like to propose a rough, more uniform design that seems initially more complicated, but is actually simpler because:

1. Everything is unambiguously on the heap.
2. Every `InventoryItem` is responsible for taking care of itself without burdening the `Inventory` with complex details of constructing and releasing `InventoryItem`s.
3. The lengths are grouped with the inventory pointers, making it simpler to have multiple inventories at one time without doing things like having an array of inventory pointers, and another array of lengths.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma region InventoryItem
/**
 * A heap-string representing an inventory item.
 * This object is intended to always be on the heap.
 */
typedef struct InventoryItem {
    char *name;
    int length;
} InventoryItem;

InventoryItem *InventoryItem_fromCString(const char *name)
{
    InventoryItem *tmp = malloc(sizeof(InventoryItem));
    
    assert((tmp != NULL) && "Critical error: malloc failed allocating memory for an InventoryItem object.");
    tmp->length = strlen(name) + 1;
    tmp->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    assert((tmp->name != NULL) && "Critical error: malloc failed allocating memory for an InventoryItem's internal string.");
    strcpy(tmp->name, name);
    
    return tmp;
}

/**
 * Weak contract: do not use the InventoryItem object after release.
 */
void InventoryItem_release(InventoryItem *This)
{
    free(This->name);
}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Inventory
/**
 * A container for a heap-array of InventoryItem objects.
 * This object is intended to always be on the heap.
 */
typedef struct Inventory {
    InventoryItem **items;
    int length;
} Inventory;

void Inventory_init(Inventory *This)
{
    This->items = NULL;
    This->length = 0;
}

Inventory *Inventory_create()
{
    Inventory *tmp = malloc(sizeof(Inventory));
    
    assert((tmp != NULL) && "Critical error: malloc failed allocating memory for an Inventory object.");    
    Inventory_init(tmp);
    
    return tmp;
}

void Inventory_addItem(Inventory *This, const char *ItemToAdd)
{
    InventoryItem *item = InventoryItem_fromCString(ItemToAdd);
    
    This->items = realloc(This->items, (This->length + 1) * sizeof(Inventory *));
    assert((This->items != NULL) && "Critical error: realloc failed expanding memory of the specified Inventory object's items array while trying to add an item to it.");    
    This->items[This->length] = item;
    ++(This->length);    
}

void Inventory_dump(Inventory *This, FILE *stream)
{
    fprintf(stream, "The inventory has %d items.\n", This->length);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < This->length; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(stream, "Item %d: %s.\n", i, This->items[i]->name);
    }
}

/**
 * Weak contract: do not use the Inventory object after it has been released.
 */
void Inventory_release(Inventory *This)
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < This->length; ++i) {
        InventoryItem_release(This->items[i]);        
    }
    free(This->items);
}
#pragma endregion

int main() 
{
    Inventory *inv = Inventory_create();
    
    Inventory_addItem(inv, "Great Sword");
    Inventory_addItem(inv, "Big Bow");
    Inventory_addItem(inv, "Excalibur");
    Inventory_dump(inv, stdout);
    
    Inventory_release(inv);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it took some time for me to understand how your code was working (as I said and as you noticed I'm a very beginner in C) and thank you for taking the time to actually make a working code that I can study.